# Find the number of seven digit whole numbers in which only 2 and 3 are present as digits if no two 2's are consecutive in any number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, permutations

> Find the number of seven digit whole numbers in which only $2$ and $3$ are present as digits if no two $2$'s are consecutive in any number?

**My Approach**:
We can make numbers and see like: $2323232$, $2333333$, $2332332$, etc. Please suggest alternate solution of this will be of great help thanks.

Comment: HInt:  try it first for 1 digit numbers, then  2 digits, then 3.  A pattern should start to emerge.

Answer (score 1):

Say $K(n)$ is the number of such n-digit numbers. Then if 2 is the first digit, the second digit must be 3, and after those two digits there are $n-2$ more digits obeying the same rule, so there are $K(n-2)$ such $n$-digit numbers beginning with $23$. There are $K(n-1)$ such numbers beginning with 3. Thus we get the recursion

$$K(n)=K(n-1)+K(n-2)$$

where $K(1)=2$ and $K(2)=3$. Note the relation to the Fibonacci sequence $F(n)$. We have $K(n)=F(n+1)$, and $K(7)=F(8)=21$.

Answer (score 1):

If there are *k 3's*, there will be *(k+1) gaps* (including ends) where *2's* can be placed without being consecutive.

Also, a minimum of *3 k's* are needed to form a 7 digit # of the type needed.

$$\text{Thus ans} = \sum_{k=3}^{k=7} {(k+1)\choose (7-k)} = 34$$

*PS*

Btw, the recursion $K_n =K_{n-1} + K_{n-2}$ is ok, the computation is incorrect. 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34.